# Get language from UTF8

Tags: java, utf-8

I have several utf8 strings and need to find out the language based on the characters used. It is not important to distuingish between language using the latin alphabet like German, Dutch and English. The language that occur are arabic, korean, chinese, japanese, i.e. language with a definite character set. The strings itself are names in most cases and it can be assumed that the first character is enough for recognition.

Comment: What do you mean by "UTF-8 string"? In Java, a string is always represented as a sequence of UTF-16 code units.

Comment: @JonSkeet, Oh Ick!  Is that really true?  I'd have thought by now they would have redefined String as a sequence of Unicode _code points_.  I guess they have to maintain backward compatibility with the original definition of the 16-bit char data type.

Comment: @jameslarge: There are some methods which retrieve code points or work with code point indexes, but most of the API is around UTF-16 code units :(

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way can be using icu4j library and the method [`UScript.getScript(int)`](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4j/com/ibm/icu/lang/UScript.html#getScript%28int%29)

It detects the script per character basis. For punctuation and spacing, it returns `UScript.COMMON`. For Latin, it returns `UScript.LATIN`. For Chinese and Japanese kanji, it returns `UScript.HAN`. For Japanese kana, it returns `UScript.KATAKANA` or `UScript.HIRAGANA` (so one `HAN` doesn't prove the text is Chinese and not Japanese).

It's recommended that you iterate over codepoints of your string, but in most cases iterating over `char`s is enough.

Here's some more theory: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Script_%28Unicode%29

And here's the table with scripts defined for all the characters: http://www.unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/Scripts.txt

Answer (score 0):

In theory you can have a String (unicode 16) in java with german and chinese

you can probably maintain a list of chinese chars frequently occuring, and if they exist, assume that its chinese etc

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it would be, for each language, keep a list of ordered pairs (c, f) where c is a unique character from the language, and f is the frequency of occurrence of that character in some reasonable corpus from that language.  (Call those lists, "character histograms".)

Then, for each document, compute a character histogram from the document, and compare it to all of the known languages.  Go with whatever is the closest match.

A better way would be to compare *word* histograms.

A *practical* way would be...   I don't know.